# What is an interruptive notification in Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

The [watch face API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/drawing.html) lets you set a property called background visibility, and its value can be WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE or WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_PERSISTENT.

The documentation for the INTERRUPTIVE flag states "When this background visibility is selected, the background of the peek card should only be shown briefly, and only if the peek card represents an interruptive notification."

What is an interruptive notification and how does it differ from an ordinary notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interruptive notifications are defined by the [Notifications Design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#how_to_choose_an_appropriate_priority) as notifications that are [PRIORITY_DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_DEFAULT), [PRIORITY_HIGH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_HIGH), or [PRIORITY_MAX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_MAX). Android Wear uses the priority, along with whether vibration/sound is included in the notification in determining which notifications interrupt the user.